# Java SQL Statement - Index Array out of Bounds

Tags: java, sql, arrays

Hi i current have a query that I'm trying to run however every time i try to run this query i get an array index out of bounds, I'm not sure why this is as i have not declared any arrays in my code, can anyone help?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent argO) {

    try{
        String query="select * from Users where Username ='admin' and password='password2'  ";
        PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, text_username.getText());
        pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());

        ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
        int count=0;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            count=count+1;

        }
        if(count==1)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and password is correct");
            frmMychatApp.dispose();
            AdminPage admin = new AdminPage();
            admin.setVisible(true);
        }
        else if(count>1)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate Username and password");
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Username and password is not correct. Please Try Again");
        }

        rs.close();
        pst.close();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception is being thrown because there are no placeholders for the parameters to be filled in the query. You should use `?` characters instead of the hardcoded values:

```
String query="select * from Users where Username =? and password=?  ";
PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setString(1, text_username.getText());
pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());
```

Comment: You are correct but what I'm try to achieve is to have the try block execute the line of code when the username='admin' and the password='password'